# CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Every time I am creating a `maven` simple project i am getting below error.
Please let me know what might the solution. I have tried many ways to resolve it but failed. what might be the reason?

Is this because of eclipse or because of repository or any certificate issue?

> CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
>        compiler-plugin:3.1

[image]

Comment: Check first if you project will compile on command line...which means on command line to run `mvn clean package` and afterwards try to import it into Eclipse...

Comment: If i ran the project using mvn clean package i am getting below type errors--

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:c
lean (default-clean) on project maventest: Execution default-clean of goal org.a
pache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven

Comment: .plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved
: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:
jar:2.5 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: Failed to read artifact
descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: Could not transfer a
rtifact org.apache:apache:pom:3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/m
aven2): C:\Users\CK\.m2\repository\org\apache\apache\3\apache-3.pom.part.lock (T
he system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 80):

I have solved this by using the eclipse "Update Maven Project" (ALT+F5) feature and check the option "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases".

Answer (score 9):

Yes, when we check "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" for Updating maven project the error is resolved and it works fine.

- Press ALT+F5 to open sub-window "Update Maven Project" feature or You
  can right click on your project -> Maven -> Update Project
- Check the option "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you read the error details, it says, plugin is cached and not pulled/pushed from/to remote repository. Hence we should do force update, by using the eclipse "Update Maven Project" feature and check the option "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases".

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is, go to the working directory through command prompt where pom.xml was available and execute the command **mvn clean package -U**

Answer (score 0):

If the same project is opened in another eclipse or any other IDE in parallel and while trying to build the same project I got the same error. After closing it and rebuild the same, it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

Add compiler plugin to pom.xml and then update maven project

Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```